# C-like Code snippets definition in javaScript

Tags: javascript, c, for-loop, c-preprocessor

In C, you can do something like this:

```
#define NESTEDFOR(i,j,n) for(i=0; i<n; i++) for(j=0; j<n; j++)
```

So you can use `NESTEDFOR(x,y,200)` to save time, because it will be replaced with `for(x=0; x<200; x++) for(y=0; y<200; y++)`

I suppose there is no way to do this in JavaScript since it's an Interpreted language, but I'm not sure.

Is there any way to do it in JavaScript?

Comment: It's true you can do horrible things like this in C, but I don't agree that they save time, and in general that sort of thing is very much not recommended.

Comment: Well, you can define functions to abstract it. It isn't any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, that isn't actually C either - it is the cpp macro language.  You can configure your system to use the cpp processor on your Javascript but many here would consider that an act of *great evil*.  I actually do that for all of my Javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript doesn't support an exact equivalent, but you can define it as an iterator -- similar to [iterator methods for `Array`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods):

```
function nestedFor(n, fn) {
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (false === fn(i, j)) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

nestedFor(200, function (i, j) {
    // etc.
    // `return false` to stop looping
});
```

Also, one option for some argument validation:

```
function nestedFor(n, fn) {
    if (typeof n !== 'number' || !isFinite(n)) {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid argument: Expected a finite number.');
    }
    if (typeof fn !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('Invalid argument: Expected a function.');
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: I think you should add a test to make sure that `fn` is function before starting the loops.

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted Yeah, there's a lot you can add to it. It should probably check that `n` is a `Number` at least, and possibly that it's positive (or adjust to support decrementing) and isn't `Infinity` or `NaN`. But, was just trying to show the simplest form and keep it close to the snippets in the question.